# looping through list of object Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, list, foreach

in my app.factory I am trying to create a for loop to loop through an array of objects.  I need to access each array index's busNumber value.  I am not sure how to accomplish this.   They way I have it now, I get "undefined" for the busNumber value.  Below is my code.

```
var _updateDevice = function (updatedDevice, deviceId) {
    alert("in updateDevice");
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // testing

    var numDevicesForBus = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < _deviceList.length; i++)
    {
        if(_deviceList[i].busNumber == updatedDevice.busNumber)
        {
            alert("found match for bus number");
            numDevicesForBus++;
        }
    }
    if (numDevicesForBus == 0) {

        alert("bus not have a device until now:  " + numDevicesForBus);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `_deviceList` ?

Comment: its a list that contains an object.  each object has an id, name, busNumber, etc

Comment: Maybe busNumber was not defined for some of the objects. Anyway, how do you know you 'get "undefined" for the busNumber value' ? It is not returned or printed anywhere. Also, this doesn't seem to be anyhow specific for angularJS, please remove the tag and add a javascript.

Comment: you are not returning anything as of now. where do you get `undefined` ?

Comment: when i do an alert(_DeviceList[i].busNumber) in the for loop it displays undefined

Comment: Where does `_deviceList` reside? In the factory or in a controller. You should probably post some more code, because the comments indicate taht people don't get it.

Comment: @Stc5097 why you used promise here? what is the need of it>